# My IDE cant find a library that I had imported. Error: "package does not exist"

Tags: java, libraries, mcmc

I'm trying to work with Hydra library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/hydra-mcmc/) in my NetBeans IDE, but it seems like IDE ''cant see'' the library at all. I've made a screen shot:

[image]

I've imported Hydra .jar file by clicking on "Libraries" and "Add a Jar". The packages are properly listed on the right (you can see it on the picture).

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: It sure looks like you imported the files from a parent folder (I notice your package name in the screenshot starts `"Hydra "`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just downloaded the jar, and it looks like it's been packaged wrongly. As @Elliot says, the screen-shot shows the packages starting *Hydra*.

Maybe try importing `Hydra.org.omegahat.Probability.Distributions.UnnormalizedDensity` and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, seems like this `jar` is not a `jar`, it should be a `zip` or `tar.gz`. It has not only the classes, but also doc, change-log, and some pdf..... change it to a `zip` and unzip it. And package it as a `jar`.